# React Native: Image not loading on IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In a React Native project, I am using the following code to get the image from the server and display it.

```
<Image source={{uri: `https://infuraa-club.appspot.com/ImageResizer?categoryId=4844470512123904&width=400&height=400`}} style={styles.thumbnail} />
```

And, the style is defined as

```
thumbnail: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
},
```

Everything Works well on **Android**, but not on **IOS**

I tried loading other images from different servers, 
ex (http://books.google.com/books/content?id=PCDengEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api) and it worked fine in both the platforms.

Not sure what's wrong with the images served from my server.

**Things I have already tried,**

- looked at http/https issues
- looked at http headers
- loaded other static images from my server with JPG/PNG extensions, Worked!
- Changed the content type to jpg and png

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: please share the stylesheet for styles.thumbnail

Comment: thumbnail: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Solution.

The Problem was not with React Native, The Problem was in the server.

I was returning the **byte[]** and **Content-Type: image/png** and HTTP Status as **HttpStatus.CREATED**

I just Changed the **HttpStatus.CREATED** to **HttpStatus.OK** and everything started working

Hope it helps others..